# Can't "run as" domain user, but can logint interactively

Tags: active-directory

I'm building virtual network of Windows Server 2008 r2 servers. I have installed domain controller in windows server 2008 r2 mode, joined another server to domain, created domain account.

I can't "Run as..." with this user on server, but can login interactively. I've already granted login as service permissions.

How this problem could be solved?

Comment: After adding accunt to local policies there are SID, not login name, in policies

Comment: Finally I solved th problem. All virtual machines used one base image, user SID on each macines contains same computer Id. Theese caused problems. I've ran sysprep on base image and rebuilt VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue a couple of times. On the "Run As" window make sure you type in the domainname\username instead of just the username itself.

Comment: I typed different variations, but still have "access denied".

Comment: Did you look at the security events on the DC to see if you see a authentication event?

Comment: Problem solved, see question comment.